# Does an array of strings need a maximum dimension in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Do I need to declare the maximum dimension of the array or is there a way to have the array scale as I add items?

Comment: You want [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: a "string of arrays" ? You sure you don't mean an "array of strings" ? I concur with @HolyBlackCat. A dynamic expandable `std::vector<std::string>` is typical when doing something like accepting arbitrary numbers of input data.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, an array of strings

Comment: And no, you don't need to declare a "maximum".  Just keep adding elements to your vector until you're done :)

Comment: @paulsm4 You do need a maximum if you use an array.

Comment: @Peter that's why you don't use an array.

Comment: @paulsm4 Obviously. But for a new user who asks "Does an array need a max dimension?" the comment "no, just keep adding elements" without mentioning that it refers to vectors is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Every array has a fixed size which is a part of its type and cannot be changed:

```
#include <cstddef>

int main() 
{ 
  const std::size_t sz = 5;
  int iarr[sz];
  return 0;
}
```

Here, the size of the array is 5, meaning it holds maximum 5 elements. Trying to add more is undefined:

```
iarr[5] = 10; // undefined
```

Although the behavior is undefined, if you tried to assign out-of-bound, the compiler wouldn't hold you back. Thus, you need to struct your code in a way to avoid such cases:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
{
  iarr[i] = 10;
}
```

This code here is perfectly legal and quite likely what you usually want. But if you are using C++11 or later, you can use the range-based for loop and have the compiler worry about the size:

```
for (auto &elm : iarr)
{
  elm = 10;
}
```

This example does the exact same thing.

Having said that, the best practice is probably to always use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Using a vector object, you don't have to worry about the size of the container, and you can just keep adding elements:

```
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
  std::vector<int> ivec;

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i) // you may replace 5 any with non-negative integer
  {
    ivec.push_back(10);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After collecting all the necessary elements, iterating over the vector object to see all its elements is again very easily possible with the range-based for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

int main() 
{
  std::vector<std::string> svec;

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
  {
    svec.push_back("hello");
  }

  for (const auto &elm : svec)
  {
    std::cout << elm << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Comment: Thank you! But, I have a problem, I dont know how many lines does it have the .txt document I want to introduce in my strings vector

Comment: @Souni: Ayxan's reply is very good.  Specifically: 1) He contrasts an "array" with a "vector".  They're similar ... but you DON'T need to know how big a vector is in advance.  If you use a vector, you don't need to declare an initial size.  2) Likewise, with a "for()" loop you usually need to know the #/items, but with a "while()" loop you don't.  For example, to read a file, your loop might be something like `while (!feof(fp)) {...}` - you'd just read until end-of-file.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a fixed size determined at compile time. So yes, if you use an array then you'll need to come up with a number of elements which will likely not be exceeded but is at the same time not unnecessarily excessive. While it can be useful to go through possible use cases and data sets to make that estimation of an upper limit, it is often impossible to come up with a hard upper limit, simply because nobody can see the future.

Additionally you'll have to keep track of the number of elements which are actually occupied, and because you usually cannot be totally sure of any practical upper limit you'll have to check against exceeding the array size nevertheless.

For that reason it is recommended to use `std::vector` which keeps track of the number of its elements and allocates new memory as needed.

Comment: How I can view all the elements i have introduced in the vector string?

Comment: The elements in the string *vector*, you mean? As in @Ayxan's answer.